# method is not defined in Javascript when I use Web Logger for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, logging

It's really strange when I try to dump logs to the Web page.

I have basic application (in xcode) with Web plugin that allows me to pull logs from iPhone to web page.

But, somehow, when I try to call method placed in other js file, I get:*"method" is not defined*.

xcode-Web structure:

[image]

Snippets of socket.html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/script.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(main);

        // Run when document.ready fires
        function main() {


            $('#btnClear').click(function() {

                clearTable();
            }); 

        }
 ....
 </script>
```

The `clearTable` is method defined in `src/js/script.js` file and I know its loaded because `onLoad` method has called.

Snippets of script.js:

```
$(function() {

   ....

  function onLoad(){
    ....
   }

   function clearTable(){
    ....
    }

onLoad();
});
```

Does someone know the reason?

I coped this project to linux and all work fine. All dependences work good.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of scoping issue, `clearTable` is defined within an anonymous function so it will be available only within that scope.

You are trying invoke it from another scope where it is not available.

The solution is to define the clearTable in the global scope. ex

```
$(function() {

    // ....

    function onLoad() {
        // ....
    }

    window.clearTable = function() {
        // ....
    }

    onLoad();
});
```

Problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HZyfA/) 
Solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HZyfA/1/)

Another solution

```
var clearTable, isAutoScroll; //Declare these as global variables
$(function() {

    // ....

    function onLoad() {
        // ....
    }

    //note this is a function variable and there is no `var`
    clearTable = function() {
        // ....
    }

    //note there is not `var` used while defining the variable
    isAutoScroll = false;

    onLoad();
});
```

Comment: AFAIK it will not work anywhere, except if there is a bug in the browser scope implementation

Comment: Can you confirm the same behaviour with the fiddles I posted

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, :) can you, please, help me with arguments initiated in other file? Do I need to go by the same way?

Comment: in script.js I have  $(function() {var isAutoScroll = true;.....}); and socket.html dosnt see it. So i need write like: var windows.isAutoScroll = true;

Comment: it is the same problem with the visibility of the variable because of local scoping, if you want to share them across then make them global variables

Comment: Thanks, but interesting that on my server I dont need do that. Good to know

Comment: I would recommend doing it since this is how it is supposed to work